# Meaning of же in “его сыновья ... его же дочери”

Tags: idioms

I’m deciphering a modern transcription of [ревизские сказки](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B7%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%B8) (revision records) written in the 19th century. All throughout I see a pattern similar to this (names have been changed):

> - Илья Андреевич Ростов
> - его сыновья:
>
>   - Николай
>   - Петр
> - Ильи Андреевича жена Наталья Николаевна
> - его же дочери:
>
>   - Вера
>   - Наташа

The sons are listed first under “его сын” or “его сыновья”, then the wife and then the daughters under “его же дочь” or “его же дочери”. What does the word же mean in this context? If it's for emphasis, it seems odd to always emphasize “his daughters” but never “his sons”. Would the meaning change if же were left out?

(By contrast, the [исповедная роспись](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%98%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C) or confession records for the same time and place list sons and daughters after husband and wife under the heading “дети их”.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The particle **же** is used here as an extra reminder that the pronoun **его**, *used for the second time*, **still** refers to the person mentioned above. It is not necessary and is just intended to make reading a bit easier (bookish style).

**P.S.** An example with the nominative case of the pronoun (**он же** in the meaning 'it was **still him**').

> **Он** [or a name here] исполнял партию Томми во всех исполнениях
>   одноимённой рок-оперы. Впоследствии **он же** исполнил партию Иуды в одной
>   из поздних записей известного мюзикла.

Answer (score 3):

It means "also", **"also his daughters"**, nothing more. The meaning won't change if you don't use it at all. But the formal official style was like that. First they named men, they were more important, because it somehow was connected with payment, then they listed women, as additional information. That's why they used "же"(also).

Comment: i think "also" emphasizes "daughters" rather than "his"

Answer (score 2):

An English equivalent is the word "**same**" used as a replacement for a noun or a pronoun

> Ilya Rostov, his sons, daughters **of the same**

With inanimate owners in English **thereof** could be used with the same meaning.

In enumeration of items belonging to the same owner or acts performed by the same actor **же** precedes the last item to connect it with the same referent which was already mentioned earlier, especially if its connection with that referent would seem unlikely or unusual just to emphasize that it still refers thereto.

> Он сам делал кладку, штукатурил, стелил полы *и он **же*** разрабатывал
>   проект